# Google Charts Dashboard - "View" property on ChartWrapper not working

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a Google Charts dashboard with multiple charts all based on the same dataset. Different charts require different columns of the data, though, and every time I try to limit the columns in the ChartWrapper view, I get an error. Here's my code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar', 'controls']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

function drawDashboard() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Institution', 'Ineligible', 'Active', 'Closed With Outcome', 'Closed Outside Process', 'Closed Without Outcome',
    'Eligibile'],

    ['CAC', 144, 35, 38, 4, 175, 115 ],

    ['SPF', 62, 2, 12, 1, 93, 4 ],

    ['CM', 69, 18, 10, 7, 64, 32 ],

    ['IP', 36, 4, 28, 24, 38, 62 ],

    ['EVM', 77, 7, 8, 2, 78, 19 ],

    ['RMC', 63, 5, 9, 1, 62, 18 ],

    ['MRI', 17, 5, 1, 5, 8, 3 ],

    ['IRM', 8, 0, 2, 1, 10, 5 ],


  ]);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
        document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  var iamFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'iam_filter',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'IAM',
      'ui': {
        'caption': "Choose mechanisms",
        'label': '',
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowWrapping',
        'cssClass': 'ChartControl',
      }
    },


  });

  var columnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    'containerId': 'id_outcomes',
    'options': {
      colors: ['#1b5869', '#42bb9a', '#bec3c7', '#9953b5', '#4c96da'],
      animation: {
        "startup": true,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'out',
      },
      legend: { position: 'right'},
      bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
      isStacked: true,
    },   
    'view': {'columns': [0,2,3]},
  });
  dashboard.bind(iamFilter, columnChart);

  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

In the above example, the error I get is:

> Invalid column index 3. Should be an integer in the range [0-2].

But if I change it to 'view': {'columns': [0,2]}, the error I get is:

> Invalid column index 2. Should be an integer in the range [0-1].

The view property works fine on the ControlWrapper, but I need it to work on the ChartWrapper, since a single ControlWrapper needs to filter data for multiple charts.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: It is a bug caused by the startup animation option.  If you disable just the startup animation, then it works as expected.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much; this was driving me crazy.