# Using data.group for Google Visualization Tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dataset with 1 key and two values, like below:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anh | 6 | 8 |
| Zavier | 2 | 3 |
| Trey | 5 | 5 |
| Zavier | 5 | 9 |
| Anh | 1 | 2 |

I would like the to create a table that groups A by the sums of B & C like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anh | 7 | 10 |
| Zavier | 7 | 12 |
| Trey | 5 | 5 |

The following code groups A by the sum of B:

```
var nationalSummary = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'Table',
          'containerId': 'nationalSummary_div',
          dataTable: data,
      'options': {
        'width': '100%',
        'rowCount': 'enable',
        'allowHtml': true,
        'alternatingRowStyle': true,
        'cssClassNames': {
          tableCell: 'large-font',
          headerCell: 'nsHeaderCell',
          }
          },
            'view': {
                'columns': [0,1]}
        });

  var container = document.getElementById('buildingDetail_div');
  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {

  var nationalSummaryNew = table.getDataTable();
  var nationalSummaryArray = google.visualization.data.group(nationalSummaryNew,[{
      column: 0,
      type: 'string',
      label: 'Column A'        
      }], [{
      column: 1,
      type: 'number',
      label: 'Column B',
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
      }]);
```

When I try to modify the code to include Col C, I modify the end of "nationalSummary" from:

```
            'view': {
                'columns': [0,1]}
```

to

```
            'view': {
                'columns': [0,1,2]}
```

and "nationalSummaryArray" to:

```
  var nationalSummaryArray = google.visualization.data.group(nationalSummaryNew,[{
      column: 0,
      type: 'string',
      label: 'Column A'        
      }], [{
      column: 1,
      type: 'number',
      label: 'Column B',
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
      }], [{
      column: 2,
      type: 'number',
      label: 'Column C',
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
      }]);
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid column index 2. Should be an integer in the range [0-1].
```

How do I add Column C? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding behind options (as a sixth line):

```
animation: {
        "startup": false,}
```

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458132/google-charts-dashboard-view-property-on-chartwrapper-not-working) there's a bug in that, just to give it a try!

Comment: Thank you. Are saying to put it after options and before view columns? I put it there first and then inside of options but the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the following QUERY function:

```
=QUERY(A1:C5,"SELECT A, SUM(B), SUM(C) GROUP BY A")
```

- `GROUP BY Col` - Aggregate rows for the given `Col` as "key"
- `SUM(Col)` - Sum the aggregated column values defined by `Group by`

##### Documentation reference:

- [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [QUERY Syntax](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)
- [Aggregation functions](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#aggregation-functions)
- [GROUP BY](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#group-by)